# Nginx / Apache Gateway Timeout

Tags: apache, nginx

I am running a VPS Server under Apache with Nginx as reverse proxy, the main reason for the server is to host my Magento store. One module in Magento runs a command that imports data content, this needs a fair amount of time to run.

I decided to use Nginx as a reverse proxy to get Varnish to work under HTTPS, since i made the move the module in magento times out exactly after 5 minutes.

This is the part of the nginx.conf which i presume may help me get an answer from you:

```
http {

    ## Basic Settings ##
    client_body_buffer_size        128k;
    client_body_timeout            30s; # Use 5s for high-traffic sites
    client_header_timeout          30s; # Use 5s for high-traffic sites
    client_max_body_size           1024m;
    keepalive_timeout              90s;
    open_file_cache                max=200000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_errors         on;
    open_file_cache_min_uses       2;
    open_file_cache_valid          30s;
    port_in_redirect               off;
    reset_timedout_connection      on;
    sendfile                       on;
    server_name_in_redirect        off;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size  1024;
    server_names_hash_max_size     1024;
    server_tokens                  off;
    tcp_nodelay                    on;
    tcp_nopush                     on;
    types_hash_max_size            2048;
    proxy_connect_timeout          1200s;
    proxy_send_timeout             1200s;
    proxy_read_timeout             1200s;
    send_timeout                   1200s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout           1200s;
    uwsgi_read_timeout             600s;
```

What am i missing?